# Change of Basis Proof example

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B_1$, $B_2$ be bases for $\Bbb R^n$ and let $C_1$, $C_2$ be bases for $\Bbb R^m$. Prove, If $T : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ is a linear transformation, then $\operatorname{rank}$(M(T,$B_1$,$C_1$)) = rank(M(T,$B_2$,$C_2$)).

So far what I have is, since T is a linear transformation then there exists matrices M(T,$B_1$,$C_1$) $\in M_{m\times n}$ and M(T,$B_2$,$C_2$) $\in M_{m\times n}$. And I figure we could use the rank+Nullity theorem in here but I am not sure where to go with it.

Answer (score 1):

There are change of bases matrices $B$ and $C$ such that $BB_1=B_2$ and $CC_1=C_2$.  These change of bases matrices have rank $n$ and $m$, respectively.  So, you only need to show that the rank of $BB_1$ and $CC_1$ have the same rank as $B_1$ and $C_1$, respectively.

Comment: but how would I show that?

Comment: @Liz Both The nullspaces of both $B$ and $C$ are trivial.  So, a vector is in the nullspace of $BB_1$ or $CC_!$ if and only if it is in the nullspace of $B_1$ or $C_1$.